# Printing Huffman Frequency Table

Tags: java, huffman-code

I'm working on some Huffman coding, and I would like to be able to print the frequency table.

However, I tried the below code and got a 'incompatible types: Entry cannot be converted to Entry
        for (Map.Entry entry : freq.entrySet())' error. Is there a way to fix it where I would possibly be able to be able to display the Frequency Table where it would be more in a table or array-like form instead of a map form?

```
public static void buildHuffmanTree(String text)
{   // count frequency each character and store it in a map
    Map<Character, Integer> freq = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0 ; i < text.length(); i++)
    {
        if (!freq.containsKey(text.charAt(i)))
        {
            freq.put(text.charAt(i), 0);
        }
        freq.put(text.charAt(i), freq.get(text.charAt(i)) + 1);
    }

    // Create a priority queue to store nodes of Huffman tree
    // Notice that highest priority item has lowest frequency
    PriorityQueue<Node> pq = new PriorityQueue<>((l, r) -> l.freq - 
    r.freq);

    for (Map.Entry<Character, String> entry : freq.entrySet())
    {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When traversing the entry set, the value type specified does not match the value type of the entries in the actual hashmap. The actual value type of each entry is `Integer`, but you're currently using type `String` in the for loop. So I'd suggest changing the for loop to

```
for (Map.Entry<Character, Integer> entry : freq.entrySet())
{
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue());
}
```